Aftermarket stereo wiring help for 2012 chevy colorado WT
I'm trying to install a cheap Android auto stereo in 2012 Chevy Colorado work truck. I bought the recommended harness adapter which was a Scosche GM05B. When I first looked at the adapter harness compared to the plug in the truck things just didn't seem right. Tried searching to make sure this was the right adapter for a 2004 to 2012 Colorado and I kept finding the same part or other parts from other manufacturers that had the exact same layout. The adapter harness has a yellow wire for B1, red for b2, blue with white for B3 and orange with white for B4. When lining this up with the OEM harness in the dash it looks like only B1 would even meet another wire and it's the orange wire. The other three look like they would match up with nothing.
Also the harness I bought has the orange with white wire in before and also has an orange wire for B12. The bag that it came in says that both of these wires are for illumination / dimmer but doesn't specify which should be used in any given situation. Regardless things that I read online said that this should not require any pinout changes and they are meant to be a straight drop in unit without having to make any changes per se. Just doesn't make sense to me. Having a hard time finding a diagram that will tell me what the wires on the OEM harness in the dash actually are. The speaker wires are obviously pretty easy to tell but other than that I only seem to have black with white stripe which obviously would be the ground (which does match up with the black ground on the adapter harness A12), and then an orange wire in what would match up with B1 of the adapter harness which is the yellow constant battery power wire, and then two solid purple wires that would match up with A1 and A2 of the adapter harness where there are no wires to match up with. These two purple Liars are set far away from what I would think of all the other speaker wires so they don't appear to be the rear right speaker wires which is what the purple wires are on the adapter harness.
I haven't done any of this stuff since I was a teenager and I'm no whiz at it by any means. Any help was appreciated. I am a hot tub technician by trade but haven't done much with cars and a long time. Does anybody know where I can get a good diagram to tell me what all these Flyers are on the OEM harness? Or can somebody recommend a straight drop in adapter harness that doesn't need any changes because something obviously isn't right here... I did try pluggin
g it into the new stereo for the hell of it because everyone who sells these adapters say no changes are needed ( at least at first glance) but I had no power to the unit as I expected..
[



Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Your truck has different wiring requirements depending on presence or absence of OnStar and /or in-dash tweeters. Have a look at the Crutchfield website, pretend you'll be buying from them to see details and see what's involved. You can purchase installation instructions from them if it helps.

Appreciate the tip. Ill do that. I did also find a different harmess @ autozone that seems more legit but its like $80 and caters to a lpt of features this truck doesnt have. I dont even have steering wheel controls... just most basic 2012 colorado Work Truck.. Thanks again.
